# How to get and post data or share data between web app and mobile app?

Tags: node.js, .net, angular, mongodb, react-native

I have a web application where a doctor can see their appointments, Now I created a mobile app that patients can use to book their appointments. The problem is how can I integrate both and share data between both the apps.

I used angular and.NET Core,MS SQL for web App and react native,Node js,MongoDB for mobile app

Comment: They need to share a backend

Comment: You can create APIs for your required work and then use that in mobile using axios or fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A visual of what Abe and Rohit has explained above:

[image: typical shared backend service]